# Define control sequences in terms of control sequences

Tags: macros, latex3

I want to set up aliases for changing control sequences using composed control sequence names. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \name { some~text }
\cs_new:Npn \cmnd { command }

% \cs_new:cpx { \cmnd alias } { \exp_not:c { name } }
% The above works, but having a \cs_new:cpc
% would be even more concise. Let's try:

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:Npn { cpc }
\cs_new:cpc { \cmnd alias } { } { name }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \commandalias
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find the correct syntax for the second argument to the generated `\cs_new:cpc` denoting the parameters.

Is it even possible to define a `\cs_new:cpc` variant?

Comment: Are you looking for `\cs_new_eq:NN` (or the variant `\cs_new_eq:cc`)?

Comment: No, I want an alias that changes whenever the underlying command changes. The `_eq` variants would not do this. You could say I am looking for the `_eq:cc` syntax with LaTeX2 `\def` functionality.

Comment: `\cs_new:cpc` doesn't make sense: `c` is always a variant of an `N` type argument, never of an `n` type argument.

Comment: `\cs_new:cpn { \cmnd alias } { \use:c { name } }`. In plain TeX it would be `\expandafter\def\csname\cmnd alias\endcsname{\csname name\endcsname}`; and in plain LaTeX `\@namedef{\cmnd alias}{\@nameuse{name}}`.

Comment: You could define a macro `\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_define_alias:NN #1#2 { \cs_new:Npn #1 { #2 } }` and then generate a variant `\my_define_alias:cc` and use that: `\my_define_alias:cc { \cmnd alias } { name }`

Comment: @Manuel's solution is just one expansion step away from my `\cs_new:cpx { \cmnd alias } { \exp_not:c { name } }`. So it seems this is the closest we get. I took the freedom to compile an answer from your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all a `c` variant is always a variant of an `N` type argument so `\cs_new:cpc` implicitly suggests there is a macro `\cs_new:NpN`. So this doesn't really make sense. Let's see where it fails:

If you do

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:Npn {cpc}
```

and use

```
\cs_new:cpc {foo} {bar}
```

then the macro never sees the opening brace it needs to see since the call is equivalent to

```
\cs_new:Npn \foo \bar
```

You can verify this:

```
\cs_new:cpc {foo} #1 {bar} {baz} % \cs_new:Npn \foo #1 \bar {baz}
\show \foo
```

shows

```
> \foo=\long macro:
#1\bar ->baz.
```

I suggest a different solution:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xzs_define_alias:NN #1#2
  { \cs_new:Npn #1 { #2 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xzs_define_alias:NN {cc}
```

and then use

```
\xzs_define_alias:cc { \cmnd alias } { name }
```

Comment: How does `\cs_generate_variant` even work with `cpc`?

Comment: @Manuel it creates `\cs_new:cpc` to expand to `\exp_args:Ncpc \cs_new:Npn`. `\cs_new:Npn`  doesn't care that `\exp_args:Ncpc` doesn't have an `n` type argument. It takes the csname created from the last `c` argument as part of the parameter spec.

Comment: It was more of a rethorical question, I was surprised. I don't know how exactly does the macro know when a `p` parameter ends. That's pretty intelligent if it really works :).

Comment: @Manuel `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_new:Npn {Npv}` works fine. (I don't know if this really is recommended, though, or if it even is useful…)

Comment: Indeed, they added at least some intelligence to that command. The `p` arguments are looked until the first `{` so for instance instead of `Npv` if you use `NpV` you need to enclose the token list for instance in braces. Not perfect, but better than I imagined.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't fit into the `\cs_new:...` scheme.

You can freely define your own function:

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xzs_make_alias:NN
 {
  \cs_new:Npn #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xzs_make_alias:NN { cN, Nc, cc }
```

after which

```
\cs_new:Npn \name { Name }
\xzs_make_alias:cc { alias } { name }
```

would define `\alias` to expand to `\name`; indeed, `\cs_show:N \alias` gives

```
> \alias=\long macro:->\name .
```

But, for your own sake, *don't* call this `\cs_new:NN`. ***Never*** use in your functions prefixes reserved by the team (except when generating variants, which is not the case).

Answer (score 1):

As clemens noted, `c` has to be a variant of an `N` type argument. So the problem lies with the fact that something like `\cs_new:NN` does not exist. But it can easily be made. From there, the variant requested can be generated.

```
\cs_new:Nn \@@_cs_new:NN {\cs_new:Npn #1 { #2 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \@@_cs_new:NN { cc }
```

Comment: You can't use those prefixes, it would be better to call it `\xzs_cs_new:NN`  or may be more descriptive `\xzs_cs_new_alias:NN`.

Comment: Please don't define macros which look like kernel commands (`\cs_new:NN` ). Use your own module name instead (`\xzs_alias:NN`). (also you're missing the parameters in the definition.) If you like I'll compose an answer from comments myself

Comment: I added `@@_` to denote a local auxiliary function. If you know how to incorporate the parameter argument, feel free to edit.